# Would someone know the right way to test AWS secretsmanager using botocore.stub

Tags: boto3, aws-secrets-manager, botocore

I am trying to use botocore.stub to test a function that wraps the boto3 Secrets Manager . Here is my function from the SecretsManagerAdapter class I wrote

```
def get_secret(
        self,
        secret_id: str,
        region: str,
        service_name: str = "secretsmanager",
        version: Optional[str] = None,
    ):
        """Gets a secret using the secret_id
        Version (if defined) is used to retrieve a particular version of
        the secret.
        Parameters:
            secret_id (string), required, name of secret in SecretsManager
            region (string), required,  AWS region
            service_name (string), optional, name of service (defaults to 'servicemanager')
            version (string), optional specific version of secret.
            Returns:
                secret (str)
        """

        session = boto3.session.Session()
        client = session.client(service_name, region_name=region)

        try:
            kwargs = {"SecretId": secret_id}
            if version is not None:
                kwargs["VersionStage"] = version
            secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(**kwargs)
        except ClientError as e:
            self.handle_client_error(e)
        else:
            # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
            # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
            if "SecretString" in secret_value_response:
                self.secret = secret_value_response["SecretString"]
            else:
                self.decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(
                    secret_value_response["SecretBinary"]
                )
            if self.secret is not None:
                try:
                    self.secretJSON = json.loads(self.secret)
                    return self.secretJSON
                except ValueError as e:
                    return self.secret
            else:
                return self.decoded_binary_secret.
```

I would like to test this  and came across botocore.stub library, below is my test code

```
import botocore.session
from botocore.stub import Stubber
from datetime import datetime

def test_secret_manager_adapter():
 client = botocore.session.get_session().create_client("secretsmanager")
 with Stubber(client) as stubber:
        stubber.add_response(
            "get_secret_value",
            {
                "Name": "secret",
                "SecretBinary": b"bytes",
                "SecretString": "secret",
                "VersionStages": [
                    "1.0.0",
                ],
                "CreatedDate": datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            },
            {"SecretId": "secret"},
        )
        secret = adapter_class.get_secret("secret", "eu-west-1")

        assert secret == "secret"
```

But I always get SecretAdapterException("ResourceNotFoundException") error, the actual secrets manager is invoked not the stubber (mock) function.
Could anyone suggest where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: I found a solution if anyone comes across this , us the moto python library. us the @mock_secretmanager decorator, using "from moto import mock_secretsmanager". see this example https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/tests/test_secretsmanager/test_secretsmanager.py